# What is the XPATH for a simple sibling?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri, siblings

Sample:

```
<p>
 <span class="label">Name:</span>  PeterPan<br>
 <span class="label">Tag:</span>   Critical<br>
 <span class="label">Priority:</span>  223<br>
</p>
```

I am using the code below and I get:

```
Name:|
Tag:| 
Priority: 

doc.xpath("//p/span").each do |para_tag|
   puts para_tag.text
end
```

but I need following details:

```
Name: PeterPan | Tag: Critical | Priority: 223
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using functional-style programming to create a map from the labels to the values:

```
labels = Hash[
  doc.css('span.label').map do |s|
    [
      s.text[0..-2],   # get rid of the trailing colon
      s.at_xpath('following-sibling::text()').content.strip
    ]
  end
]
p labels
#=> {"Name"=>"PeterPan", "Tag"=>"Critical", "Priority"=>"223"}
```

Or more simply we can just show them:

```
doc.css('span.label').each{ |s| puts "#{s.text} -- #{s.next_sibling}" }
#=> Name: --   PeterPan
#=> Tag: --    Critical
#=> Priority: --   223
```

*Using [`next_sibling`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-next_sibling) to find the following text and taking advantage of the fact that [`Nokogiri::XML::Text#to_s`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Text.html) gives the text contents.*

Answer (score 2):

If the current node is:

```
<span class="label">Name:</span>
```

then this XPath expression:

```
following-sibling::node()[1]
```

selects the wanted text node:

```
"  PeterPan"
```